# Usage of poetic device

Tags: poetic

> Real eyes realize real lies.

Is this sentence illustrating the usage of alliteration? If not, which poetic device has been employed here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alliteration, yes, but it also puns on the three homophones. Actually, the third, 'real lies', isn't a quite a hompophone, because the stress pattern is different.

Comment: Yes. And it's hard to keep up for more than one stanza in English. If you know Spanish, try Octavio Páz's "La Palabra Dicha", the first poem on [this page](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/poemas.html). The last couplet is "Inocencia y no ciencia:/Para hablar aprende a callar."